# HTML multiple file input hangs when selecting many files from file browser

Tags: html, web

I have noticed that if I have an input of type file with the 'multiple' tag, when I click on it and attempt to select approximately 1000 images, my browser will hang for about 2 minutes before becoming responsive and adding the files. This doesn't seem to happen when I drag and drop the same files onto the input however. Even only selecting 50+ files from the file browser causes a longer delay than dragging and dropping the 1000 files.

Does anyone have an explanation as to the possible differences between these two methods of adding files? I've been testing with a completely barebones html file, and it happens on the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari. If it's just the way things are I might try to prevent users using the file browser to select files!

What I'm testing with:

```
<body>
  <input id='file-input' type='file' multiple>
</body>
```

Comment: Limiting accepted file types, does that help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Comment: @Rustyjim Thanks for the suggestion but I'm afraid not, even if I limit it just to .jpg it still exhibits the same behaviour. I just don't understand the differences between the two methods of selecting files!